# Any screen sharing program freeze entire system after starting demonstration

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, graphics

i'm newbie to Linux.
First, when i tried to use some screen sharing app it just shows black screen. I swithced from Wayland to X11, and it started to work fine, but after a few seconds the system freezes.
I stuck into this problem while using Discord on Manjaro Linux (KDE). I thought the problem was in Electron, but it wasn't (because screen sharing in Telegram freezes the system too). Then i checked Linux Mint on Cinnamon where everything worked fine, but i don't like it. My friend suggested me to use Fedora Linux (also KDE). But the problem repeated there, so i tried to use GNOME instead of KDE but nothing changed. Are there any solutions or reasons for what happened? I think the problem is in my video drivers, because  on Windows 10 and Linux Mint everything work fine. For my friends who use Linux everything works fine too.

[image]